Can cold-deck imputation used to address class imbalance?
If you have experience on using cold-deck imputation to address class imbalance problem in the dataset, could you please share more details or reference papers?
Edit to add:
The modeling methodology is Neural Network with one hidden layer. The data is imbalanced with less than 1% population with positive tags.
For context, below is description of cold deck imputation on wiki.
Hot-deck
A once-common method of imputation was hot-deck imputation where a missing value was imputed from a randomly selected similar record. The term "hot deck" dates back to the storage of data on punched cards, and indicates that the information donors come from the same dataset as the recipients. The stack of cards was "hot" because it was currently being processed.
One form of hot-deck imputation is called "last observation carried forward" (or LOCF for short), which involves sorting a dataset according to any of a number of variables, thus creating an ordered dataset. The technique then finds the first missing value and uses the cell value immediately prior to the data that are missing to impute the missing value. The process is repeated for the next cell with a missing value until all missing values have been imputed. In the common scenario in which the cases are repeated measurements of a variable for a person or other entity, this represents the belief that if a measurement is missing, the best guess is that it hasn't changed from the last time it was measured. This method is known to increase risk of increasing bias and potentially false conclusions. For this reason LOCF is not recommended for use.
Cold-deck
Cold-deck imputation, by contrast, selects donors from another dataset. Due to advances in computer power, more sophisticated methods of imputation have generally superseded the original random and sorted hot deck imputation techniques. It is a method of replacing with response values of similar items in past surveys. It is available in surveys that measure time intervals.

Is class imbalance even a problem in need of remedy, either cold-deck imputation or another technique?

Please, please, please read the many posting about the myth of class imbalance on this site.  You are going down a wormhole.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't see how imputation of missing values relates to imbalance anyway? Maybe in that the imputed values "ought to" depend on the class, so that sorted hot imputing tends to impute wrong values on the rare class?

I see your edit. Yes, that is what imbalance means, so you are indeed in a situation where there is imbalance. Among others, Frank Harrell and I dispute the notion that imbalance is a problem in need of any kind of remedy.
